# how to remove space from html using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make html page as show in image having desktop item and mobile item .I am using bootstrap css + angular .

why white space come ..Here is my code 
http://plnkr.co/edit/G8mp53rQlF562hEkgmgT?p=preview

here is my image[image]

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ionic']);

    //myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

    function MyCtrl($scope,$http) {
        $http.get("menu.json").success(function(data){
         $scope.menu=data;
        }).error(function(){
             alert('error')
        })
    }
```

**Secondly**

what to use in bootstrap when it display on desktop it show **three** item in row as show in desktop image below and if it display on mobile device it display vertically  as show in image
**Mobile Item**
[image]

**Desktop**

[image]

updated one
http://plnkr.co/edit/G8mp53rQlF562hEkgmgT?p=preview

how to come in single vertical column when user move desktop to mobile version

Comment: Have you tried using a minus margin?

Comment: in your bootstrap.css there is `.navbar {  margin-bottom: 20px;}`, set margin to `0px` and the white space will be gone

Comment: could you please tell about second question.how to make three for desktop and vertically for mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why white space come

Bootstrap, by default, adds a 20px margin below the navigation to prevent your next element from sticking to it. I suggest you move your green background color to `body` instead of your next element. That way, your page gets a uniform green (avoids the white gap) and your items are properly spaced away from the nav.

> what to use in bootstrap when it display on desktop it show three item in row as show in desktop image below and if it display on mobile device it display vertically as show in image Mobile Item

Bootstrap has a 12-column grid system. It uses the convention of `col-*-*` where the first asterisk denotes a "break" (when the grid styling changes, depending on page width) and the second asterisk is the column size (1-12, 12 being full-width). Since you need 3 items, then you need a width of 4 for each of the 3 items.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">item1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">item2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">item3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">Lorem ipsum dolor...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering could you make plunker or edit the my plunker with same answer

Comment: @user944513 no. That's your job.

Comment: I understand but how it come in one column in mobile version ?

Comment: sir I understand all points but how it come on one vetical line when it is on mobile version

Comment: see it always in three column when width is small .it is not coming down when in single column